# How do file pointers point to the of data on the disk?

Tags: pointers, memory, disk, portable-executable, file-pointer

I'm reading the Microsoft documentation that says:

"

> PointerToRawData is a file pointer to the first page within the COFF file.

"

PointerToRawData is a variable in the PE section headers. Question is, how can a file pointer point a page (which is a chunk of data that is in MEMORY, as far as I know), meanwhile it is supposed to point to the first block of the file on the disk? (which is on the disk not the memory, obviously)

Also do file pointers also work the same way as pointers that point to a location in the memory? are they also displayed as hex numbers like 0xfff2ab23 or something when you print them out? does the system also reference the locations on the disk the same way it does with the memory? (using hex values).

My knowledge is very limited in this regard, excuse me for that. I'm trying to improve and hopefully I will by your help.

Comment: I don't think they mean the memory page. Maybe they refer to the equivalent term on the disk side. The **hex notation** does not have any relation with accessing any memory or disk location. It is just a **notation**, nothing more. Finally, **`PointerToRawData`** is just **an offset** in the file that points to the data belonging to the section, it is aligned with the file alignment requirement which is mostly *512*, as stated in the documentation.